# Is there any hack for IE support of CSS Variable?

Tags: css, css-variables

I am using CSS variable for theme-color and theme-background but my code does not work on IE. Is there any hack for IE support of CSS Variable?

```
/* Declaring variable*/
:root {
  --theme-color: #323232;
  --theme-bg-color: #af0069;
}

/* Using variable */
.btn {
  background: var(--theme-bg-color);
  color: var(--theme-color);
}
```

Comment: Nope. Best bet would go Sass or import a fallback stylesheet.

Comment: @Roberrrt  I'm working on a offline project based on JavaScript, HTML and CSS only, in which I can't add any SASS support :(

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support variables. But you can use CSS preprocessors like LESS or SASS.

```
@themeColor: #323232;
@themeBgColor: #af0069;

.btn {
    background: @themeBgColor;
    color: @themeColor;
}
```

Comment: OP stated he cannot use Sass though

Comment: I'm working on a offline project based on JavaScript, HTML and CSS only, in which I can't add any LESS or SASS support :(

Comment: @Roberrrt That's not stated in question.

Comment: It was added in a comment while you were answering it, yes. Then again, this would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Low-key solution which will only be usable in this case:

Finish your project, and then duplicate your CSS file, Find-and-replace all of your `var(--theme-bg-color);`'s with the respectable colors: `#323232;`.

This will result in you having to redo this step in each iteration, but will guarantee a fully supported website, even in Internet Explorer.

Comment: What's the use of var's then?

Comment: Consistancy throughout development.

Comment: The whole idea of variables in CSS is consistancy. The end-user will never see any advantage of the usage in the first place, so sticking with this solution in the development phase will yield the best results. (Besides, OP is requesting a 'hacky fix' for variables, and a 'find-and-replace' solution is definitely 'hacky'.

Comment: So nice @Roberrrt but this is exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: The alternative would be Sass. But I very much understand why you do not want to do this.